# Is it possible to work with scalaz in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-2.8, eclipse-3.6, scalaz

- Create a new scala project
- add library reference to scalaz
- create a new package
- create  a scala file in the package
- set encoding to UTF-8
- paste the content of [the bifunctor example](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleBifunctor.scala.html)
- adjust the package in the file

It works in intellij. With eclipse i get 8 errors like this:

> ';' expected but something found

in the lines containing assert_≟ .

*I'm using Eclipse Helios with Scala IDE for Eclipse 1.0.0.201011110258.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Are you using the correct character set (e.g. UTF8) for you source files?
- Are the Eclipse "errors" from the IDE itself, or from a compilation run (an invocation of `scalac`?
- Can you `scalac` compile the source file manually?

Assuming it is not a fie encoding problem and that you can manually compile the file, I might conclude that, as scalaz uses complex type inference, Eclipse might be reporting erroneous errors.

Comment: On Eclipse, i open File/Properties and set UTF-8 encoding. Anyway, the same file works with IntelliJ.

Comment: I have found. The problem is that Eclipse editor is buggy with encodings. I had to change file encoding via JEdit to set UTF-8. Before doing this i got the same errors invoking scalac manually. Thank you for the help.